# Run Additional Commands on a Specific PID

Tags: process, firefox

I'm completely new with Linux so forgive me if this seems like an absurd question.

I am trying to open new tabs on Firefox without a url from the terminal. So my command is:

`$ firefox -new-tab -search foo1`

Now when I try to do it again in the hopes that it opens a new tab searching for a new item, say:

`$ firefox -new-tab -search foo2`

it opens a new window instead. So I had this thought that maybe if I could get the PID of the previous browser I could run the new tab command on that PID, and so the new tab actually opens on the same window. I can get the PID with relative ease if I run:

`$ firefox -new-tab -search foo1 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

But actually using the PID to execute a new command on that PID is what I completely have no idea of.

Any and all input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `ps -aux | grep firefox` ??

Comment: I don't see any way to force a new command onto an existing process, even if you know its Pid. How would Firefox be able to process a new set of arguments in its `main()`? The mechanism in Netscape Navigator was that a new Navigator was launched, and it used an inter-process API to tell the existing process to open a new tab, and then would terminate itself (there were many other similar features too). Firefox may have a similar interface. Anyway, I am looking at one Firefox showing just the Home page, and `ps` sees seven Pids: Parent, Socket, and five tabs (four of them invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firefox browser you're interacting with, no matter how many windows it shows, is only one "master" PID (with actual website workers running in their own processes and communicating with the main process through some well-defined interfaces), anyways. There's no 1:1 correspondence between "window" and "PID".

So, sadly, working around that firefox command line bug (`--search` always opening a new window) won't work the way you think it would.

I've thought about this, but there's sadly no way to tell firefox to open a new tab and execute a query to the default search engine there, without writing a browser extension or instrumenting the browser in another program.

So, the best I can offer you is this:

1. Pick the search engine of your choice, and note the query URL. (The easiest way is to search for a random string, say "qwert", and then mentally replace that with a placeholder, e.g. `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=qwert` becomes `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=<placeholder>`
2. use that URL with `--new-tab`:

```bash
searchword="strange women lying in ponds distributing swords"
encoded="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "${searchword}")"
firefox --new-tab "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=${encoded}"
```

There's more than one way to weigh a duck, obviously. I would much have preferred to use `firefox --new-tab "$(trurl --url 'https://duckduckgo.com/' --append "query=q=${searchword}")"` over the Perl invocation, but `trurl` isn't yet available on many Linux distros.

Anyways, no matter how you do it, this is not very nice to use. To make it nicer to use, you'll want to put this in a text file called "websearch":

```bash
#!/bin/bash
searchwords="$@"
encoded="$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "${searchwords}")"
firefox --new-tab "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=${encoded}"
```

let's assume it is in a directory called `bin/` in your home directory; make it executable by running `chmod a+x ~/bin/websearch`. Now you can use it:

```bash
~/bin/websearch What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow
```

Comment: This is the way I did it, thanks! I realized that the beginning part of the url is always the same, and the thing you search is just it but with whitespaces replaced with "+". combining these two you will get a url like how you would normally search on the engine

Comment: @lems that works if you never use characters like `:`, `&`, `/`, `#`, `"` or `ü`. See my name why I find that unsatisfactory.